# $D^{k+1} f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in E$ then $f$ is polynomial of at most degree $k$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: E \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $E$ is open connected set, and $D_{k+1} f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in E$ then $f$ is a polynomial in $x_1 ,x_2, \cdots ,x_n$ of degree at most $k$ ?

Similar proof we did for one-variable function, but the multi-variable thing here is the thing i am unable to handle

Comment: Take any point in $p\in E$ and take the first $k$ terms of the Taylor expansion at $p$, so that you have a polynomial $Q$ in a neighborhood of $p$. Consider the function $g=f-Q$. Along any line passing through $p$ you know that $g(p)=0$ and that $g$ is a polynomial of degree $\le k$, whose first $k$ derivatives vanish at $p$, so $g=0$ on the line; hence $f=Q$ in a neighborhood of $p$. Then use connectedness. I hope this helps.

Comment: Two variable case : let $h(t) = f(tx,ty)$. $\ D^m h(t) = ?$ then integrate $D^{k+1} h$ $\ \ k+1$-times.